# Pymssql : Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

When I try to connect with the server database I am getting the below error:

> pymssql._pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for
> an unknown reason.

Code snippet:

```
import pymssql  
conn = pymssql.connect(server='test.myserver.abc.com', user='xxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxxx', database='my_db')  
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

How can I fix this issue? Or is there any way to encrypt the database connection?

Comment: Maybe you need a mssql connector

Comment: I need for MSSQL @ChristianH

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad, long day.

Comment: Consider switching to other connection methods, such as pyodbc, because as of 2019 [The Pymssql Project is Being Discontinued #668](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668).

Comment: I tried to connect to pyodbc, but how can I make sure it works on azure environments?@AlwaysLearning